# Meaning of if(something.length) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, integer, ternary-operator

I was parsing some smooth-scrolling code online (at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) and found the line `if (target.length) {some stuff}`. Doesn't the `.length` operator return an integer? How does this work with the `if()` statement, as I thought they take only true/false values? The same `target.length` was used as the condition for a ternary statement slightly earlier in the code.

Comment: See [All falsey values in JavaScript](//stackoverflow.com/q/19839952). Zero is falsy value so the body of `if` will not execute when `target.length` is zero. This is used as a guard of errors what'll occur when trying to access some property/method which does not exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement in JavaScript returns true for any number greater (or less) than zero, and false for 0 (there are many more rules beyond this which I will not mention for this question).  Hence in your code snippet

```
if (target.length) {some stuff}
```

The `some stuff` would be evaluated if the `target` had a non zero length.  If the `target` had a zero length, possibly indicating that it were empty, the `some stuff` content would not evaluate.

Comment: There is a small correction - JavaScript returns true for any number greater than zero==> for negative numbers also it will return true

Answer (score 0):

1. if value is not the same type, then it will be converted
2. in this case if length is 0(zero) - "false" value; any value which is not 0(zero), below and above are considered "true"

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the concept of truthiness. [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) is a great resource to see which values are truthy or falsy in javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
if (target.length) {
  do something
}
else {
  goes here... 
}
```

here let assume length is greater than or equal to 1,
interpreter will take it as `true`.... otherwise it will be `false`

in the same case,

if your **target is 1**

you can still use

```
if (target) {
   do something ..
}
else {
   goes here ..
}
```

but here if target is 2 it will go on to 2.

because as per boolean logic **1 will be consider as true** and **0 will be false**